# Combinar mais de uma condição em um if tenário

Tags: java, if

É possível combinar mais de uma condição no if tenário? Exemplo:

```
boolean existe = pessoa tem 23 ou pessoa tem 22 ? true : false ;
```

Estou tentando mas não consigo.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seria isso?

```
boolean existe = (idade == 22 || idade == 23);
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, era isso mesmo.

Comment: Aproveitando se o que você quer retornar for booleano não precisar do if ternário basta escrever a condição. Eu uso if ternário quando quero retornar algum valor que não seja booleano tipo: `(idade == 22 || idade == 23) ? "Sim": "Não"; `

Answer (score -2):

É possível sim:

Se você quer necessariamente usar o operador ternário (como perguntado):

```
boolean existe = pessoa.getIdade() == 23? true : pessoa.getIdade() == 22? true : false ;
```

Mas nesse exemplo não seria necessário usar esse operador:

```
boolean existe = pessoa.getIdade() == 23 || pessoa.getIdade() == 22;
```